# Element http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema:complexType is invalid in this context

Tags: c#, xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xml-validation

I'm trying to validate this XML file

```
<session>
    <mic id="1" posname="T1" x="0.0" y="0.0" z="0.0" />
</session>
```

using this XSD file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema 
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    attributeFormDefault="unqualified" 
    elementFormDefault="qualified">

    <xs:element name="session">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="mic" type="micType" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="4">
                </xs:element>

                <xs:complexType name="micType">
                    <xs:simpleContent>
                        <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                            <xs:attribute type="xs:int" name="id"/>
                            <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="posname"/>
                            <xs:attribute type="xs:float" name="x"/>
                            <xs:attribute type="xs:float" name="y"/>
                            <xs:attribute type="xs:float" name="z"/>
                        </xs:extension>
                    </xs:simpleContent>
                </xs:complexType> 
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

but I get this error message:

> XmlSchema error: Element http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema:complexType is invalid in this context.

If I just have the attribute definition for the mic element the program runs fine. I don't know what I'm doing wrong. I'm trying to have the XSD validate the data types for the mic element. Can anybody please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have is a non-viable hybrid of a local and global declaration of a complex type.  Either define a `micType` globally (as Michael Kay mentioned) or locally:

### Global complexType declaration

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
           attributeFormDefault="unqualified" 
           elementFormDefault="qualified">
  <xs:element name="session">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="mic" type="micType" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="4"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:complexType name="micType">
    <xs:simpleContent>
      <xs:extension base="xs:string">
        <xs:attribute type="xs:int" name="id"/>
        <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="posname"/>
        <xs:attribute type="xs:float" name="x"/>
        <xs:attribute type="xs:float" name="y"/>
        <xs:attribute type="xs:float" name="z"/>
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:simpleContent>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

### Local complexType declaration

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
           attributeFormDefault="unqualified" 
           elementFormDefault="qualified">
  <xs:element name="session">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="mic" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="4">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:simpleContent>
              <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                <xs:attribute type="xs:int" name="id"/>
                <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="posname"/>
                <xs:attribute type="xs:float" name="x"/>
                <xs:attribute type="xs:float" name="y"/>
                <xs:attribute type="xs:float" name="z"/>
              </xs:extension>
            </xs:simpleContent>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Either way is ok and will successfully validate your XML.

Comment: Thank you so much for explaining this and giving a code snippet. it works now.

Answer (score 2):

The complexType named micType should be defined as a global type declaration, i.e. it should be an immediate child of the xs:schema element.

Comment: thank you for this suggestion. this comment lead to a solution I dont know if I can flag 2 answers though so I accepted the answer with the code snippet. I have never used xml before let alone xml validation so im really glad that you guys, kjhughes included, took the time to help me with this